# Paso de parámetros a una función de un archivo .py desde una función en una class App en otro archivo .py

Tags: python

Expongo el escenario:

archivo_funciones.py

```
- funcion1(datos):
     Insertar datos en la base de datos
 - funcion2():
```

archivo_app.py

```
    class App:
    
        def __init__(self):

            def insertar_datos()
                Desde aquí necesito llamar a la funcion1.py en archiv_funciones.py y pasarle parámetros
```

Y ahora me explico:

El problema es que necesito pasar a la funcion1 del archivo_funciones.py, los datos recogidos en una ventana en forma de tupla [] desde el archivo_app (donde esta la aplicación principal), para ello la funcion1 admite el parámetro datos y desde al archivo_app la función que recoge los datos debe poder pasarlos para insertarlos en una base de datos.

Explicado con el código por si se ve mejor:
archivo_funciones.py contiene varias funciones entre ellas:

```
def insertar_datos_fam(datosfam):
    try:
        crear_tablas()
        con = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO Familia VALUES (null, ?)', datosfam)
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        print("Datos guardados correctamente")
```

Y desde al archivo_app.py tengo lo siguiente:

```
class App:

        def __init__(self):
    
            # Boton guardar familia
            def guardar_fam():
                datos_fam = [nombre_fam.get()]
                return datos_fam
                insertar_datos_fam(datos_fam)
```

Esta función de botón guardar familia esta dentro de la clase App y de: def **init**(self)

Por más que he buscado y leído no encuentro la forma de hacer que los datos recogidos puedan pasar a la función en el otro archivo.

Mencionar que he importado archivo_funciones.py fuera de la class y reconoce la función pero me indica que el código de la llamada es inalcanzable.

Comment: Cual es el error que te da? No concozco ningún error en Python que diga que algo es "inalcanzable". De que modo estás importando el modulo archivo_funciones? Quizá el error proviene de allí.

Comment: 1. Has intentado importando el archivo? 2. Tienes un return y lo que está despues de eso no se ejecuta

Comment: El error de llamada inalcanzable me lo da Pycharm. Si, también he intentado importando el archivo pero yo creo que el problema esta en que la función que captura los datos esta dentro de la función def __init__ aunque no se porque...

Comment: "inalcanzable" o "unreachable code" te va a figurar en la línea insertar_datos_fam(datos_fam) porque está posterior a un return, es decir, ese código nunca se ejecutará. si hacés justo después de datos_fam  = .... un print(datos_fam) se ven los datos? Si se ven en consola entonces el problema es ese, no los inserta porque sale de la función antes.

Comment: christian, acertaste! el return impedía la ejecución de la función. Todo funciona correctamente. Un gran error de principiante. Muchas gracias por el aporte!.

Comment: Corercto Marcelo, asi es, tambien lo apunto christian. Muchas gracias por el apunte tambien, acabo de probar el codigo al suprimir el return y todo va correctamente.